# "ImportError: cannot import name views" on Flask server but in PyCharm works

Tags: python, flask

At the beginning, I'm newbie at Flask.

I received a working project made in Python using Flask framework. It worked in PyCharm. When I pasted it into server files and run flask server (I followed documentation on Flask site), the error has shown:

```
File "/home/web/app/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
from app import views, models
ImportError: cannot import name views
```

So that is the **init**.py file:

```
1 import os
2 from flask import Flask
3 from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
4 from flask_login import LoginManager
5 from flask_openid import OpenID
6 from config import basedir
7
8 app = Flask(__name__)
9 app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
10
11 db = SQLAlchemy(app)
12
13 # Imports below help me fixing the database
14 # from app import models
15 # import database_migrate
16
17 lm = LoginManager()
18 lm.init_app(app)
19 lm.login_view = 'login'
20 oid = OpenID(app, os.path.join(basedir, 'tmp'))
21
22 from app import views, models
23
24 app.run(debug=True)
```

When typed *print(app)* it shows *None*. All the modules are installed. Tried to run simple webapp printing "Hello world", and it worked. Flask has been reinstalled three times. Views has *from app import app*
I couldn't find any solution on stack or in any other place. 

 Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is `views.py` exactly? Same directory with `__init__.py` or under some other directory?

Comment: Same directory as `__init__.py` is

Comment: It is possible, that is a path issue but you can change the line `from app import views, models` to `from . import views, models`

Comment: Thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 1):

As your `views.py` and `models.py` are in the same directory, you can replace import statement with:

```
from . import views, models
```

for proper import. As an alternative, you can also move them under a directory and put that directory name instead of the dot.

Answer (score 0):

I removed from `pgadmin4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgadmin/browser/__init__.py` import of `view_commit` and two lines where it use below in code. And this problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with pgadmin - **ImportError: cannot import name 'view_commit' from 'flask_security.views'**. I changed pgAdmin4\v5\web\pgadmin\browser\__init__.py

```
from flask_security.views import _security, view_commit, _ctx
```

to

```
from flask_security.views import _security, _commit, _ctx
```

and the error disappeared.